# How can I load a .txt file containing html tags without interpreting it by html?

Tags: javascript, html

When i load a .txt file containing html marks using FileReader() method and I try display it on the screen, it show me already interpreted code. Here is a problem, because I need these tags too, without interpreting it by html. For example: 
instead of:

```
Some text in file.txt
```

I want to get:

```
 <p>Such text in file.txt with these html tags</p>
```

Here a code what I'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/fkwugnsn/. Try now load a txt file with the content of html. You see that it's already interpreted by html. And I need no interpreted code.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: You could search for `<` and `>` in whole file and replace it with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the content with `createTextNode` and `appendChild` (or `replaceChild`) instead of assigning it to `innerHTML` (as I presume you are doing).

```
var node = document.createTextNode(mytext);
someElement.appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for this:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

This function will replace `&`, `<`, `>` and `"` with html entities.

[source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/)